# Mostrar codigo PHP dentrode JS

Tags: php, javascript, formularios

Me gustaria poder mostrar codigo PHP dentro de mi codigo  dentro de mi ejemplo.
En mi select mando a mi codigo Js el 1 o el 2 segun es el caso selecionado,

```
si $Select1 = 'buenos dias'
y  $Select2 = 'buenas tardes'
```

Me gustaria mostrar esto cuando se imprime el resultado:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myCiudad").value;

if (x.match("1"))  {   
    document.getElementById("JSciudad").innerHTML = "<br>'<?php echo $Select1?>'<br>";} 
if (x.match("2"))  {   
    document.getElementById("JSciudad").innerHTML = "<br>'<?php echo $Select2?>'<br>";}  
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Porque no lo haces todo en javascript?

Comment: hola alan, por que uso el codigo php para mandar elformulario y jugar con este valor ya que laciudad tiene el id correspondiente a los usuarios asignados en esta en la tabla SQL y me seria util que en $select2 fuese igualal nombre del usuario(s) correspondientes para que los muestre , pero en mi ejemplo esta lomas basico que me hace falta :(

Comment: Si interprete bien tu pregunta, se hace exactamente como mostras en el bloque de código

Comment: Hola Juan Salvador Portugal , elproblema es que no se por que no lomuestra :( tengo que agregar algo en la etiqueta de script o en el header o algo asi?

Comment: Hola ya lo solucione es agregando un json_encode  "<?php echo json_encode($Select2); ?>";